# Applying logical check on data frame renames column

Tags: r

I have an R data frame that looks like:

```
x<-c(1:10)
df<-data.frame(x)
df['y']<-(df['x']>5)
```

This should give me `false x5, true x5`.

However, when I do this, it renames `df['y']` to `x`.

How do I make it do the evaluation I want without renaming the original column header?

Thanks

When I do this I get the following output:

```
    x    x
1   1   FALSE
2   2   FALSE
...
10 10    TRUE
```

Comment: `df[,'y']` with the comma?

Comment: da da. Thanks so much.

Comment: Sorry, I have a mistake in my original code. Fixed

Comment: I had a mistake in my original code. Fixed now, it should have been `([df['x']>5)` rather than `(x>5)`

Comment: When I do that, it gives my data frame a new, second, column called `x`. Replicated by: `x<-c(1:10) \n df<-data.frame(x) \n df['y']<-(df['x']>5)`. I am in R 3.2.2

Comment: It genuinely doesnt work for me. It produces a second column in the data frame also called x. The *values* in the second column are absolutely correct, its just the column name of the second column that is wrong. I've also replicated the bug on an independent machine running Rstudio.

Comment: The desired out put in this case is what it looks like at face value - for values of `x` less than or equal to 5, it would report `FALSE`. For values of `x`>5, it would report `TRUE`. That part is absolutely fine. The problem for me is that it comes out with `colnames(df)  ------> x, x` rather than `colnames(df) -------> x, y`. This issue is fixed as mentioned in first comment by doing `df['y']<-(df[,'x']>5)`, i.e. specifying the comma. Seems weird that it renames otherwise, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try various column replacements and see what happens:

```
> x<-c(1:4) ; df<-data.frame(x) ;
> df
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

This is how I'd do it - create a new column from the other column:

```
> df$y=df$x>2
> df
  x     y
1 1 FALSE
2 2 FALSE
3 3  TRUE
4 4  TRUE
```

Version 2, get the assignment your way, with single square brackets:

```
> x<-c(1:4) ; df<-data.frame(x) ;
> df['y']=df$x>2
> df
  x     y
1 1 FALSE
2 2 FALSE
3 3  TRUE
4 4  TRUE
```

that looks fine, an x and a y column. Now check we get your behaviour:

```
> x<-c(1:4) ; df<-data.frame(x) ;
> df['y']=df['x']>2
> df
  x     x
1 1 FALSE
2 2 FALSE
3 3  TRUE
4 4  TRUE
```

Yes, two x columns. Now let's try the other way round from 2.

```
> x<-c(1:4) ; df<-data.frame(x) ;
> df$y=df['x']>2
> df
  x     x
1 1 FALSE
2 2 FALSE
3 3  TRUE
4 4  TRUE
```

Two x columns again. So it appears to be the RHS that triggers this.

The solution is *double* square brackets:

```
> df['x']
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
> df[['x']]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Single square brackets gets you a data frame, and assigning part of a dataframe from another dataframe seems to overwrite the name. Using double brackets just gets the column value, and so the name won't change:

```
> x<-c(1:4) ; df<-data.frame(x) ;
> df['y']=df[['x']]>2
> df
  x     y
1 1 FALSE
2 2 FALSE
3 3  TRUE
4 4  TRUE
```

Of course if you know the literal name you should use `df$y`, only use double square brackets when evaluating a name from a variable, eg:

```
> n="y"
> df[[n]]
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The reason an extra comma fixes this is because indexing with two indices gets you a vector, one index (single square brackets) gets you a data frame:

```
> df[,'x']
[1] 1 2 3 4
> df['x']
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a really nice answer. And it's nice to know I'm not crazy.